# How to insert a valid control template

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, styles, controls

here is the template I created in a resource dictionary

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:EntryLabelBase}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type local:EntryLabelBase}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        >
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here is the usage of it.

```
<local:EntryLabelBase Content="Username:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" />
```

This is the bug I am getting.

> 'No matching constructor found on type 'SPIS_Base.EntryLabelBase'. You can use the Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct this type.' Line number '25' and line position '10'.

Still new to wpf. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post EntryLabelBase code behind file. It looks like there is no public parameterless constructor in that class.

Comment: solved it. It was a mistake. I made the specified class abvstract accidentally.